# Fluid divs and parent height

Tags: html, flexbox, height, parent, fluid

I am creating gallery-website with few (atm 6 images) which are responsive to any screen resolution. Instead of using static height and percentage width I created a script that decides of width, height and position of every image (as a position: absolute), but the problem is that in some cases parent div (container) have less  height than a child. Why is it so?

```
    <body style="margin:0">

  <div id="kontener" style="border:1px solid black; max-width: 1100px; padding: 80px; margin: 0 auto;">
  <div id="mydiv" class="mydiv" style="width:100%; height:100%; position: relative;">

  <div id="resize1" style="border: 1px solid black; position: absolute;">
  lalala
  </div>
    <div id="resize2" style="border: 1px solid black; position: absolute;">
  lalala
  </div>
    <div id="resize3" style="border: 1px solid black; position: absolute;">
  lalala
  </div>
      <div id="resize4" style="border: 1px solid black; position: absolute;">
  lalala
  </div>
      <div id="resize5" style="border: 1px solid black; position: absolute;">
  lalala
  </div>
      <div id="resize6" style="border: 1px solid black; position: absolute;">
  lalala
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </body>
```

And there is javascript to determine divs width, height and position:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

   $('#informacja').text('Browser (Width : '
                + mydiv.clientWidth +',FULLWIDTH:'+$(window).outerWidth() + ' , Height :' + $(window).height() + ' )');
                        var w = mydiv.clientWidth;
                        var browser = $(window).outerWidth();
                        if (browser>1136) {
                                document.getElementById('resize1').style.width=(w-40)/3;
                                document.getElementById('resize1').style.height=2*(w-40)/9;
                                 document.getElementById('resize1').style.left='0';
                                 document.getElementById('resize1').style.top='0';
                                 document.getElementById('resize2').style.width=(w-40)/3;
                                 document.getElementById('resize2').style.height=2*(w-40)/9;
                                 document.getElementById('resize2').style.left=(w-40)/3+20;
                                 document.getElementById('resize2').style.top='0';
                                 document.getElementById('resize3').style.width=(w-40)/3;
                                 document.getElementById('resize3').style.height=2*(w-40)/9;
                                 document.getElementById('resize3').style.left=2*(w-40)/3+40;
                                 document.getElementById('resize3').style.top='0';
                                 document.getElementById('resize4').style.width=(w-40)/3;
                                 document.getElementById('resize4').style.height=2*(w-40)/9;
                                 document.getElementById('resize4').style.left=0;
                                 document.getElementById('resize4').style.top=2*(w-40)/9+20;
                                 document.getElementById('resize5').style.width=(w-40)/3;
                                 document.getElementById('resize5').style.height=2*(w-40)/9;
                                 document.getElementById('resize5').style.left=(w-40)/3+20;
                                 document.getElementById('resize5').style.top=2*(w-40)/9+20;
                                 document.getElementById('resize6').style.width=(w-40)/3;
                                 document.getElementById('resize6').style.height=2*(w-40)/9;
                                 document.getElementById('resize6').style.left=2*(w-40)/3+40;
                                 document.getElementById('resize6').style.top=2*(w-40)/9+20;
                        }
                        else if(browser>756) {
                            document.getElementById('resize1').style.width=(w-20)/2;
                            document.getElementById('resize1').style.height=(w-20)/3;
                            document.getElementById('resize1').style.left='0';
                            document.getElementById('resize1').style.top='0';
                            document.getElementById('resize2').style.width=(w-20)/2;
                            document.getElementById('resize2').style.height=(w-20)/3;
                            document.getElementById('resize2').style.left=(w-20)/2+20;
                            document.getElementById('resize2').style.top='0';
                            document.getElementById('resize3').style.width=(w-20)/2;
                            document.getElementById('resize3').style.height=(w-20)/3;
                            document.getElementById('resize3').style.left='0';
                            document.getElementById('resize3').style.top=(w-20)/3+20;
                            document.getElementById('resize4').style.width=(w-20)/2;
                            document.getElementById('resize4').style.height=(w-20)/3;
                            document.getElementById('resize4').style.left=(w-20)/2+20;
                            document.getElementById('resize4').style.top=(w-20)/3+20;
                            document.getElementById('resize5').style.width=(w-20)/2;
                            document.getElementById('resize5').style.height=(w-20)/3;
                            document.getElementById('resize5').style.left='0';
                            document.getElementById('resize5').style.top=2*(w-20)/3+40;
                            document.getElementById('resize6').style.width=(w-20)/2;
                            document.getElementById('resize6').style.height=(w-20)/3;
                            document.getElementById('resize6').style.left=(w-20)/2+20;
                            document.getElementById('resize6').style.top=2*(w-20)/3+40;
                        }

                        else {
                            document.getElementById('resize1').style.width=w;
                            document.getElementById('resize1').style.height=2*w/3;
                            document.getElementById('resize1').style.left='0';
                            document.getElementById('resize1').style.top='0';
                            document.getElementById('resize2').style.width=w;
                            document.getElementById('resize2').style.height=2*w/3;
                            document.getElementById('resize2').style.left='0';
                            document.getElementById('resize2').style.top=2*w/3+20;
                            document.getElementById('resize3').style.width=w;
                            document.getElementById('resize3').style.height=2*w/3;
                            document.getElementById('resize3').style.left='0';
                            document.getElementById('resize3').style.top=4*w/3+40;
                            document.getElementById('resize4').style.width=w;
                            document.getElementById('resize4').style.height=2*w/3;
                            document.getElementById('resize4').style.left='0';
                            document.getElementById('resize4').style.top=6*w/3+60;
                            document.getElementById('resize5').style.width=w;
                            document.getElementById('resize5').style.height=2*w/3;
                            document.getElementById('resize5').style.left='0';
                            document.getElementById('resize5').style.top=8*w/3+80;
                            document.getElementById('resize6').style.width=w;
                            document.getElementById('resize6').style.height=2*w/3;
                            document.getElementById('resize6').style.left='0';
                            document.getElementById('resize6').style.top=10*w/3+100;

                        }

    $(window).resize(function () {
        var w = mydiv.clientWidth;
        var browser = $(window).outerWidth();
        $('#informacja').text('Browser (Width : ' + mydiv.clientWidth
                                                +',FULLWIDTH:'+$(window).outerWidth()
                                 + ' , Height :' + $(window).height() + ' )');
                        if (browser>1136) {
                                document.getElementById('resize1').style.width=(w-40)/3;
                                document.getElementById('resize1').style.height=2*(w-40)/9;
                                 document.getElementById('resize1').style.left='0';
                                 document.getElementById('resize1').style.top='0';
                                 document.getElementById('resize2').style.width=(w-40)/3;
                                 document.getElementById('resize2').style.height=2*(w-40)/9;
                                 document.getElementById('resize2').style.left=(w-40)/3+20;
                                 document.getElementById('resize2').style.top='0';
                                 document.getElementById('resize3').style.width=(w-40)/3;
                                 document.getElementById('resize3').style.height=2*(w-40)/9;
                                 document.getElementById('resize3').style.left=2*(w-40)/3+40;
                                 document.getElementById('resize3').style.top='0';
                                 document.getElementById('resize4').style.width=(w-40)/3;
                                 document.getElementById('resize4').style.height=2*(w-40)/9;
                                 document.getElementById('resize4').style.left=0;
                                 document.getElementById('resize4').style.top=2*(w-40)/9+20;
                                 document.getElementById('resize5').style.width=(w-40)/3;
                                 document.getElementById('resize5').style.height=2*(w-40)/9;
                                 document.getElementById('resize5').style.left=(w-40)/3+20;
                                 document.getElementById('resize5').style.top=2*(w-40)/9+20;
                                 document.getElementById('resize6').style.width=(w-40)/3;
                                 document.getElementById('resize6').style.height=2*(w-40)/9;
                                 document.getElementById('resize6').style.left=2*(w-40)/3+40;
                                 document.getElementById('resize6').style.top=2*(w-40)/9+20;
                        }
                        else if(browser>756) {
                            document.getElementById('resize1').style.width=(w-20)/2;
                            document.getElementById('resize1').style.height=(w-20)/3;
                            document.getElementById('resize1').style.left='0';
                            document.getElementById('resize1').style.top='0';
                            document.getElementById('resize2').style.width=(w-20)/2;
                            document.getElementById('resize2').style.height=(w-20)/3;
                            document.getElementById('resize2').style.left=(w-20)/2+20;
                            document.getElementById('resize2').style.top='0';
                            document.getElementById('resize3').style.width=(w-20)/2;
                            document.getElementById('resize3').style.height=(w-20)/3;
                            document.getElementById('resize3').style.left='0';
                            document.getElementById('resize3').style.top=(w-20)/3+20;
                            document.getElementById('resize4').style.width=(w-20)/2;
                            document.getElementById('resize4').style.height=(w-20)/3;
                            document.getElementById('resize4').style.left=(w-20)/2+20;
                            document.getElementById('resize4').style.top=(w-20)/3+20;
                            document.getElementById('resize5').style.width=(w-20)/2;
                            document.getElementById('resize5').style.height=(w-20)/3;
                            document.getElementById('resize5').style.left='0';
                            document.getElementById('resize5').style.top=2*(w-20)/3+40;
                            document.getElementById('resize6').style.width=(w-20)/2;
                            document.getElementById('resize6').style.height=(w-20)/3;
                            document.getElementById('resize6').style.left=(w-20)/2+20;
                            document.getElementById('resize6').style.top=2*(w-20)/3+40;
                        }

                        else {
                            document.getElementById('resize1').style.width=w;
                            document.getElementById('resize1').style.height=2*w/3;
                            document.getElementById('resize1').style.left='0';
                            document.getElementById('resize1').style.top='0';
                            document.getElementById('resize2').style.width=w;
                            document.getElementById('resize2').style.height=2*w/3;
                            document.getElementById('resize2').style.left='0';
                            document.getElementById('resize2').style.top=2*w/3+20;
                            document.getElementById('resize3').style.width=w;
                            document.getElementById('resize3').style.height=2*w/3;
                            document.getElementById('resize3').style.left='0';
                            document.getElementById('resize3').style.top=4*w/3+40;
                            document.getElementById('resize4').style.width=w;
                            document.getElementById('resize4').style.height=2*w/3;
                            document.getElementById('resize4').style.left='0';
                            document.getElementById('resize4').style.top=6*w/3+60;
                            document.getElementById('resize5').style.width=w;
                            document.getElementById('resize5').style.height=2*w/3;
                            document.getElementById('resize5').style.left='0';
                            document.getElementById('resize5').style.top=8*w/3+80;
                            document.getElementById('resize6').style.width=w;
                            document.getElementById('resize6').style.height=2*w/3;
                            document.getElementById('resize6').style.left='0';
                            document.getElementById('resize6').style.top=10*w/3+100;

                        }
    });

</script>
```

[screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLdrh.png)

Comment: because you have positioned them absolutely so they take no space - the height of the parent is being determined by the height of it's parent (ie height 100%)

Comment: Then i should add the following to the breakpoints in js? I guess it's gonna work, for example:

`code` if (browser>1136) {   document.getElementById('mydiv').style.height=4*(w-40)/9+20
`code`

While w is width of container, then height will be calculated with this formula

Comment: I guess you just need to add height and width to parent div when you set all the other positioning

Comment: Thing is that I don't want to add static height in px, but using only %, so the website stays responsive at any screen and make sure there won't be too much or too less empty space on any. Anyways, thanks for your help, I changed the parent height in js and works fine now! 

(didnt work on jsfiddle so uploaded on free hosting)
https://imagenius.000webhostapp.com/responsive.php

Comment: I don't think doing all your styling with js is what people had in mind when making responsive sites, you should learn how to do css properly then you probably wouldn't have the need for most of that js

Comment: Yeah, you're pretty right, and for sure there is a way to do it in html+css. I'm gonna figure out how to do it so. Just found an useful article that will help me out, I'll leave it here, maybe someone will have the same problem:)

https://www.milessebesta.com/web-design/scaling-div-height-proportional-to-width-trick/

thanks a lot Pete